# AWS t2.micro EC2 instance running JetBrains YouTrack on port 80. Cannot access YouTrack on public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed IntelliJ YouTrack running on port 80 on a Windows Server 2012 t2.micro EC2 instance on AWS.

I am able to access YouTrack when I remote desktop into the machine and enter http://localhost or http:// or http://. Therefore I know the application is up and running on the expected port.

I have whitelisted my ip by adding the relevant inbound rule under the security group settings for the instance.

I was assuming that was the only necessary step to allow inbound connections to that specific port. However I cannot access YouTrack when I enter the public IP of the instance on my web-browser from the whitelisted IP. Also what I find more confusing is when I try to enter http:// within the remote desktop of the instance, I am still unable to connect.

What am I missing for enabling incoming connections to a port on my EC2 t2.micro instance?

I appreciate all the advice.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Windows firewall was running and blocking the connections beyond the security group settings. Opening port 80 within Windows firewall fixed the issue.

When I first ran into the issue I typed "Firewall" into the start search. First result was "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security". When I opened that I got the error "There was an error opening Windows Firewall with Advanced Security snap-in". I immediately assumed AWS eliminated the firewall service from the windows builds to force customers to prefer the security group controls of the AWS console.

Embarassingly I have just now tried the second option in the list "Windows Firewall" which showed the normal windows firewall being active and of course blocking incoming connections to port 80. I have added the exceptions to the required ports and the issue was immediately resolved.

I hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: What version of YouTrack did you install? Since 6.5, Youtrack [requires 1024M](https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546119-What-hardware-requirements-does-YouTrack-have-) to run, which is all of a t2.micro 's memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Turning off the firewall worked for me. Had been struggling with accessing my ec2 hosted application from its public ipv4 address